# Injected IPrincipal Claims empty after adding Claims Transformer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm attempting to use Claims based authorization using Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core. I have a Claims Transformer that sets user Claims. I also inject `IPrincipal` into by `DbContext` so I can access the current user when `SaveChanges()` is called to log who updated entities.

In Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User);
    services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformer>();
```

In MyDbContext.cs:

```
    protected readonly IPrincipal _principal ;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IPrincipal principal) : base(options)
    {
        _principal = principal;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // Do something with Claim value...
        await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

I've added a Claims Transformer to add some Claim info:

```
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        // Add Claims...
        return principal;
    }
```

`SaveChangesAsync` is called in User Middleware to log the access to the application. Before adding the Claims Transformer, the `IPrincipal` injected into the `DbContext` was a `WindowsPrincipal`, and it contained the Claims I needed such as PrimarySid, etc. Now after adding the transformation, it is a `ClaimsPrincipal` however the list of Claims is now empty.

Through debugging I can verify that `TransformAsync` executes before `SaveChangesAsync`, but the constructor injection in the db context occurs before the transformation (The `DbContext` is a Scoped service, the Claims Transfomer is Transient).

Summary:

- Before adding the Claims Transformer, the injected `IPrincipal` is a `WindowsPrincipal` with a populated list of Claims.
- After adding the Claims Transformer, the injected `IPrincipal` is a `ClaimsPrincipal` with an empty list of Claims.

Comment: Add it as scoped service

Comment: @Nkosi I've tried changing the other services to Scoped, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when trying to inject the IPrincipal through the DbContext constructor. I have found that the IPrincipal that was injected in the DbContext was not yet "Transformed" by the ClaimsTransformer.

I have worked around this problem by creating a UserResolverService.

IUserResolverService.cs

```
public interface IUserResolverService
{
    IPrincipal GetUser();
}
```

UserResolverService.cs

```
public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IPrincipal GetUser()
    {
        return _context.HttpContext.User;
    }
}
```

MyDbContext.cs

```
private readonly IUserResolverService _userResolverService;

// Call this whenever you need the IPrincipal object
public IPrincipal User => _userResolverService.GetUser();

public MyDbContext(IUserResolverService userResolverService, DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
{
    _userResolverService = userResolverService;
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
services.AddTransient<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();
```